# Image Tag Not Displaying Image

Tags: reactjs, image, material-ui

I am working on a web app, using React.js and Material UI. I don't know why image is not displaying on my web, I have tried almost everything I can. Here is the code where I am using the image tag.

`````
import { TextField, Grid, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import WFH1 from './images/WFH1.svg'

function IntroSection()
{
    return(
        <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={3}>
                <image src={WFH1}/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} style={{color:'white', textAlign:'center'}}>
                <Typography variant="h3">Get paid for the work</Typography>
                <Typography variant="h3"> you <span style={{color:'#3ee8e5'}}>love</span> to do.</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={3}></Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
}
export default IntroSection; ````

And here is the structure of my code:


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwRbs.png
`````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the HTML `img` tag to actually display an image:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

You are trying to use an HTML tag `image`, that not exists.

Answer (score 0):

Image tag is not exists. You have to use img tag in html.

```
<img src={WFH1}/>
```